# Translate “break even”

Tags: single-word-requests

Does anybody have any suggestions to translate “break even”? Like in the following example:

> I played poker with my friends last night. At first I was winning a lot but in the end I **broke even**.

Ie, they finished with the same amount of money as they started with.

Comment: _atingi ekvilibron_ translate.google.com proposes: _ekvilibro de gajno kaj perdo_. Maybe needs an other formulation: **nete rezultiĝis en / pendolis al nul por mi.**

Answer (score 2):

```
(finfine) mi nek gajnis nek perdis monon
```

Ekzemplo el Tekstaro:

```
La sumo de 300 milionoj da dolaroj restis
senŝanĝa ekde 1996: nek gajnoj nek perdoj,...
```

Comment: `(finfine) mi nek gajnis nek perdis grande` eble pro tio ke `break even` ne estas ekzakta.

Comment: Neil said "break even" means that one finishes with the same amount of money as one started with. In other words one neither won nor lost any. _Traduku ideojn, ne vortojn._